# Strip the first (top level) tag in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup, strip

I create a soup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<div><p>My paragraph <a>My link</a></p></div>", "html.parser")
```

I want to strip the first top-level tag to reveal its contents, regardless of the tag:

```html
<p>My paragraph<a>My link</a></p>
```

with all the children. So I don't want to find and replace by tag like `soup.find("div")`, but do this positionally.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the provided [`.unwrap()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<div><p>My paragraph <a>My link</a></p><p>hello again</p></div>","html.parser")

soup.contents[0].unwrap()

print soup
print len(soup.contents)
```

Result:

```
<p>My paragraph <a>My link</a></p><p>hello again</p>
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use its children?

`soup.findChildren()[1]` -> `<p>My paragraph <a>My link</a></p>`

`soup.findChildren()[0]` returns the element itself which contains the `div` element. So the index 1 would be the first child.

Comment: This would omit the other children under the tag, e.g. if there were another paragraph parallel to the first.

Comment: This code extracts the "first top-level tag" which is what you asked. Did you mean "tags" instead of "tag"?